# Storing files in Memory

Tags: ios

I'm trying to save a file (for security reasons) to memory so I can access it via NSFileManager to pass it to different classes which are opening files with the NSFileManager method contentsAtPath:.

Is it possible to create a file at some special path and use it like a normal file stored in the filesystem (some kind of memory disk?).

I don't want to rely on the NSFileProtection...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just trying to make sure I'm not overanalyzing this, you're only asking how to save a file to the device?

Comment: @JonMarsh No, it sounds like he wants a ramdisk as he still needs to use `NSFileManager` to manipulate the file, but wants it in memory.  I think he's out of luck here.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ah, gotcha. I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No, there is no *ramdisk*-like storage under iOS.

It looks, therefore, that you'll need to read the entire file from disk into memory (preferably as an Object) and change whatever methods you've got, that manipulate the file, to do so on the memory/object instead.